# Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications results in 500 internal error

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

What I am trying to do is to use GoogleAPI to upload images to drive (that belongs to one account).

So I am using the server to server application and trying to follow the steps in the link below to authenticate using OAuth 2.0

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#overview

Now according to google documentation, there are three steps required

1. Create a JSON Web Token (JWT, pronounced "jot"), which includes a header, a claim set, and a signature.
2. Request an access token from the Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server.
3. Handle the JSON response that the Authorization Server returns.

I have ready managed to generate JWT as in first step. However when I requested an access token I received an empty response.

So I tried to send the token request using a rest console to check only the result of the post request. The response I received was 500 Internal Error.

Following is my code

```
    $jwt_claim = '{
            "iss":"myemail.gserviceaccount.com",
            "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
            "aud":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            "exp":1328554385,
            "iat":1328550785
        }';

    if (!$cert_store = file_get_contents(base_url('assets').'/myprivatekey.p12')) {
        echo "Error: Unable to read the cert file\n";
        exit;
    }

    $cert_info = array();
    if (!openssl_pkcs12_read($cert_store, $cert_info, "notasecret")){
        echo "Error: Unable to read the cert store.\n";
        exit;
    }

    echo "Certificate Information Generated Succesfully<br>";
    //print_r($cert_info['pkey']);

    $sign = JWT::encode($jwt_claim,$cert_info['pkey'],'RS256');
    echo 'Signature <br>';
    echo $sign;

    //2. Access token request
    // Get cURL resource
    $curl = curl_init();

    // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            'grant_type' => urlencode('urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer'),
            'assertion' => $sign
        )
    ));
    // Send the request & save response to $resp
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    // Close request to clear up some resources
    curl_close($curl);

    echo '<br>response <br/>';
    echo $resp;
```

Comment: you have tagged the question with Google-api-php-client which is googles official php client library.  If you are using the client library then why are you trying to do the service account authentication yourself?   Why not use the client library?

Comment: @DaImTo I am actually not using it, and I was looking for an argument on whether it makes a difference or it might be the reason I am getting this error

Comment: I removed the invalid tag for you.   try and remember to only use the tags that are valid for your question.     Its definitely possible to do this without using the client library.  I have never been able to, I find it easer to just use Googles client library.  you might be able to get some help from the source code for the library https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client